# Xcode 7.1 "The request timed out." error

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, xcode7.1

I am trying to generate ad hoc build from Xcode 7.1. So currently Xcode try to fetch list of teams from developer portal before processing for generating build. But I am getting "The request timed out." error(many times) while Xcode fetching list of teams from the developer portal, so I can't generate build. I don't know what's the problem is. Any solution?

[image]

Also I have checked following url : https://developer.apple.com/system-status/ . But its showing whole system working good.

Comment: most likely itunesconnect is down. don't really rely on system-status page. ask this question on apple dev forum and i am sure you will not be the only one facing this issue today

Comment: The issue is persistent for some users. Like Me!! are you facing the same right now?

Comment: same issue here, it's really annoying, as anyone discovered a workaround?

Comment: Same issue here, running 7.1.1. Thanks Apple!

Comment: This is likely a network issue, Xcode Preferences doesn't have a network proxy setting entry, guessing it uses the default system network.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 7.1.1 has solved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Now woking with all Xcode with WiFi network.

I have build it with Xcode version 7.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Xcode 7.2 and the problem fixed itself.